# Remove/hide default maps layer in google maps and add image overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So basically what i'm trying to achieve is this functionality in google maps v3,that they have in openlayers: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/image-layer.html

Hide the base layer of googlemaps (the actual map), and then add a image overlay that is placed over the entire surface of the map.

Is this possible? and do anyone have any solutions at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a GroundOverlay: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay

However, while a `GroundOverlay` covers the base map, it does not remove it. You'd need a custom map type for that: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes

It would be fairly easy to develop a custom map type that always returns a blank tile.

Comment: if i set a groundoverlay with the max and min bounds (90,150 & -90,-150) the image seems to be distorted, this is probably due to take into account of the curvature of the earth, is it possible to disable this effect?

Comment: For that you'd need a custom overlay and/or projection.