# How can I turn off the map in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display an overlay in google maps and during some circumstances I don't want to see the actual map beneath it but still be able to zoom and pan. I know that I can make a large white overlay that covers the entire map and then put my overlay on top of that, but this seems inconvenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove/hide default maps layer in google maps and add image overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900868/remove-hide-default-maps-layer-in-google-maps-and-add-image-overlay)

Comment: Assuming your overlay to be `myOverlay` and the map to be `map`, then to hide, `myOveryay.setMap(null)`, and to show, `myOverlay.setMap(map)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach should be to use a style that hides all map-features.

Add this to the map-options:

```
styles:[{ stylers: [{ visibility:'off' }]}]
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.